# Issues with function meant to swap arrray indices (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, swap, indices

I wrote a function that is supposed to swap to indices of an integer array.
My issue is that when I try to implement my swap function,

**I get this error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at pa5.swap(pa5.java:24)
at pa5.nextPermutation(pa5.java:66)
at pa5.main(pa5.java:12)
```

**Here is the code**

```
     nextPermutation(A); //line 12, call to function in main()

     static void swap(int[] Q, int i, int j){
         int temp = Q[i]; //line 24 
          Q[i] = Q[j];
          Q[j] = temp;
       }

   swap(A, pivot, successor); //line 66 inside of nextPermutation function
```

I don't understand why I have this error.  I would appreciate any hints on how I may go about understanding and solving this error.

Comment: What are the contents of `A`

Comment: what's the length of the string you're using?

Comment: Did you mean swap(A, 1, 2)?  The error is obvious: Your array indexes are out of bounds for that array.

Comment: length - Array indexes start from 0. It means if there are 5 items - indexes 0 till 4.

Answer (score 0):

Call it

```
swap(A, 1, 2);
```

Not

```
swap(A, A[1], A[2]);
```

Currently you are passing array values as `i` and `j`, not indices.

Comment: My error is, more specifically, occurring when I call the swap function inside of my nextPermutation function:         swap(A, pivot, successor);
        printArray(A)

Comment: @AnnabellaSakasai What is the length of A, and what values do pivot and successor contain, when it crashes?

Comment: The length of A is 5, pivot = 8, and successor = 10.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to swap the value of the specified index like this:

```
swap(A, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have created an array of some size, lets say it is of size 'n'. Now when you are going to access n or n+1 dimension, you are getting this error.

The code that you have posted is not sufficient to pinpoint the error but I feel that for an array size of n,you are not accounting that indexes start from 0 and ends at n-1.

Comment: I am starting my index and 0 and ending at n-1.

Comment: The swap function works when called in other sections of the program.  I just don't understand the issues that occur when it is called in the nextPermutation() section.

Comment: What is the size of A,  and value of these parameters  pivot, successor;

Comment: The length of A is 5, pivot = 8, and successor = 10. I think my issue has to do with the values of pivot and successor.  The swap function works fine in other parts of the program.

Comment: Its very obvious from this right, both the values of pivot and successor are greater than  the length of the array. That is why you are getting this exception. Now your  problem  lies in the generation of these values.

Comment: I'm having trouble because I need the position of pivot and successor, their values are correct.

Comment: Those values might be correct, but the reason for this exception is the generated values are greater than the size of the array that  you re trying to access..

Comment: The value generated is not a position of the array, but a value stored at that position, which is then assigned to a variable.